# Modeling the storage of multiple data types that also have parent child relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to design a MySQL database for a project I've started but I cannot figure out the best way to do it.

Its an OOP system that contains different types of objects all of which need to be stored in the database. But those objects also need to maintain parent child relationships with one another. Also I want the flexibility to easily add new data types once the system is in production.

As far as I can see I have three options, one that is pure relational, one which I think is entity attribute value (I don't properly understand EAV) and the last is a hybrid design that I've thought of myself, but I assume has already been thought of before and has a proper name.

The relational design would consist of two tables, one large table with columns that allowed it to store any type of object and a second table to maintain the parent child relationships of the rows in the first table.

The EAV design would have two tables, one being an EAV table with the three columns (Entity id, Attribute and Value), the second table would then relate the parent child relationships of these entities.

The hybrid design would have a table for each type of object, then a parent child relation table that would have to store the id of the parent, child and some sort of identifier of the tables that these id's come from.

I'm sure this problem has been tackled and solved hundreds of times before and I would appreciate any references so I can read about the solutions.

Comment: don't use EAV. read up on Table Inheritance http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the only truly relational design:

```
CREATE TABLE Objects (
  object_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_object_id INT,
  -- also attribute columns common to all object types
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_object_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE RedObjects (
  object_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- attribute columns for red objects
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BlueObjects (
  object_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- attribute columns for blue objects
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE YellowObjects (
  object_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- attribute columns for yellow objects
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id)
);
```

But MySQL does not support recursive queries, so if you need to do complex queries to fetch the whole tree for instance, you'll need to use another method to store the relationships.  I suggest a Closure Table design:

```
CREATE TABLE Paths (
  ancestor_id INT,
  descendant_id INT,
  length INT DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (ancestor_id, descendant_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ancestor_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (descendant_id) REFRENCES Objects (object_id)
  -- this may need additional indexes to support different queries
);
```

I describe more about the Closure Table here:

- My answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- My presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
- My book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can very well use the EAV design. It works for the application we created, although after about 3 years of refinement.
You can also use a generic table structure and use any particular table for a group of objects. Or just create one generic table for each object.
Which Table for which Object is part of a metadata repository.
If you use a val_int, val_string type of structure, you will have Null columns except where the value is stored. There are sparse matrix features of MS SQL which you might consider using. Disk size is somewhat cheap these days. So the only drawback you have vis-a-vis traditional structure is NxR rows (say R Attributes for the object) instead of N rows.

Other than that, few things to look out for are object instance GUIDs, dynamic sql generation...